# Keras: model.predict for a single image

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I'd like to make a prediction for a single image with Keras. I've trained my model so I'm just loading the weights.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
import cv2

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150



def create_model():
  if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
  else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

  model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

  model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(64))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(1))
  model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

  return model


img = cv2.imread('./test1/1.jpg')
model = create_model()
model.load_weights('./weight.h5')
model.predict(img)
```

I'm loading the image using:

```
img = cv2.imread('./test1/1.jpg')
```

And using the predict function of the model:

```
 model.predict(img)
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (499, 381, 3)
```

How should I proceed to have predictions on a single image ?

Comment: Anyone know if the image is coming from s3 what a useful function to transform the data would be?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Since you trained your model on mini-batches, your input is a tensor of shape `[batch_size, image_width, image_height, number_of_channels]`.

When predicting, you have to respect this shape even if you have only one image. Your input should be of shape: `[1, image_width, image_height, number_of_channels]`.

You can do this in numpy easily. Let's say you have a single 5x5x3 image:

```
    >>> x = np.random.randint(0,10,(5,5,3))
    >>> x.shape
    >>> (5, 5, 3)
    >>> x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    >>> x.shape
    >>> (1, 5, 5, 3)
```

Now x is a rank 4 tensor!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, where does my img variable containing the image should be in your case ?

Comment: assume my variable `x` is an image. I probably should have written `x=cv2.imread('image.jpg')`. The function cv2.imread() returns a numpy array. So in your case `img` is a numpy array, and so is my `x` variable

Comment: An alternate way of doing the same is `x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)`.  Also. [np.squeeze](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) can be used to convert back to a rank 3 tensor.

Comment: Also remember, if you used ImageDataGenerator to load and train your data, you might have used rescale=1./255. Make sure to add np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)/255 if you used that...

Comment: Just nesting inside an array also did the trick for me: `x = np.array( [ x ] )`, which seems more intuitive to me in that case.

Comment: I prefer to work with ```np.newaxis``` as it uses slicing syntax, which I find easier to work with. It inserts a new axis with size of 1 by default: ```model.predict(image[np.newaxis, ...])```

Answer (score 21):

Even though this doesn't solve your error, make sure and rescale your image if you have done that previously. For instance, my training generator looks like:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
   rotation_range=40,
   zoom_range=[0.7, 0.9],
   horizontal_flip=True,
   rescale=1./255
)
```

So when I go to predict a single image:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage import transform
def load(filename):
   np_image = Image.open(filename)
   np_image = np.array(np_image).astype('float32')/255
   np_image = transform.resize(np_image, (256, 256, 3))
   np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image, axis=0)
   return np_image

 image = load('my_file.jpg')
 model.predict(image)
```

I have to also rescale it by 255.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. In order to use skimage I add `scikit-image==0.15.0` to the requirement.txt packages

Answer (score 17):

You can load the image with desired width and height, convert it to a numpy array with the shape of `(image_width, image_height, number_of_channels)` and then change the shape of the array to `(1, image_width, image_height, number_of_channels)`. (batch_size =1)

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

img_width, img_height = 150, 150
img = image.load_img('image_path/image_name.jpg', target_size = (img_width, img_height))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis = 0)

model.predict(img)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
single_test = model.predict(np.expand_dims(X_test[i], axis=0))
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 model.predict(img[None,...])
```

Comment: data formatting should be done at the preprocessing stage, not in model calls.

Comment: This is a valid answer. It's weird that this guy got downvoted. Is it because he provided no explanation? `model.predict(img[None])` would also work. And it's a lot shorter than `np.expand_dims()` stuff.

Comment: Agree, voted up this answer. @utkarsh-ankit  don't be discouraged. your answer was helpful. just provide a line of explanation please - will be so much more helpful to others