# Keras, dimension mismatch when predicting label from one instance

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, dimension

I've created a CNN that predicts spoken commands.  I'm now recording individual instances of spoken commands, extracting MFCCs, and using model.predict() to classify them.

```
y, sr = librosa.load('audio.wav')
samples = librosa.resample(y, sr, 8000)
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=samples, sr=8000, n_mels=26, fmax=4000) 
mels = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=samples, sr=8000, S=librosa.power_to_db(S))
```

However, when I use the following I get a dimension mismatch error (expected 4, received 2):

```
model.predict(mels)
```

and when I use `model.predict(np.array[mels])` as some have suggested, it gives the same error (expected 4, received 3).  Since I used MFCCs of two dimensions to train the original model, I'm not sure why it's not able to predict based on a two-dimensional array.

Comment: model.predict probably expects a batch to predict on, whereas you want to input one example only. have you tried `np.expand_dims()`?

Comment: I tried np.expand_dims but I get the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

I realized Keras requires the same batch size when predicting as when training. One answer is to build a new model using the weights of the previous and then use that to predict for batch_size=1.  An answer linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017017/keras-model-predict-for-a-single-image).