# How to convert image to 4D Tenzor?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

How to convert image to 4D Tenzor `(1,150,80,1)` `[batch_size, width, height, channels]` ?

The model on which I train in the manual receives 16 images `(16,150,80,1)`.

https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/categorical/string_lookup/

But I want to try using 1 image.

```
# 1. Read image
img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
# 2. Decode and convert to grayscale
img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels=1)
# 3. Convert to float32 in [0, 1] range
img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
# 4. Resize to the desired size
img = tf.image.resize(img, [80, 150])
# 5. Transpose the image because we want the time
# dimension to correspond to the width of the image.
img = tf.transpose(img, perm=[1, 0, 2])

# 6. Convert
# ...
```

Comment: Use `tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)` to cvt `[h, w, c]` to `[1, h, w, c]`.

Comment: @Innat You are my God, I've been trying to solve this for a day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Innat for the answer and @Vipz for confirming the solution worked. Adding the comment in the answer section for the community benefits.

```
 Use tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0) to cvt [h, w, c] to [1, h, w, c].
```